# NG services: one service issuing CORS error and other service works fine

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have 2 NodeJS express services both running in http://localhost:3000. When I run my angular APP(localhost:4200), first service runs fine and load data however the second service from child component issue CORS Error. Could you suggest why?

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/yt-vid/Shazam!' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I don't have CORS-related headers/changes in any of the service. Wondering why the first service works and other service does NOT. The only notable difference is I am calling the first service from ngOnInit and other from ngOnChanges.

```
export class NowRunningComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private nowrunningService: NowRunningServiceService) { }
  movies: Array<Movie>=[];
selectedMovie: Movie;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("MOvies length"+ this.movies);
    this.nowrunningService.getNowRunningMovies().subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.movies= data.results;

    });

  }
}
```

Second service call:

```
export class MovieDetailComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges {

  @Input()
  selectedMovie:Movie;
  constructor(private ytService: YoutubeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('movie detail init');
  }
  videos:Array<any>=[];
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    console.log('movie changed');
    console.log(`Changes: ${JSON.stringify(changes)})`);
     if(this.selectedMovie != null && this.selectedMovie.title!= null)
      {
        this.ytService.getYTvideos(this.selectedMovie.title).subscribe((data:any) => {
          this.videos= data.items;

        });
      }
  }

}
```

YoutubeService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YoutubeService {

  search_url:string = "/yt-vid/";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getYTvideos (title:string) {
    console.log("Youtube service called");
    return this.http.get(globals.api_base_href+this.search_url+title);

}
}
```

NowRunningServiceService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NowRunningServiceService {
pagenum:number=0;
apiUrl ="/now-running/";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getNowRunningMovies() {
    return this.http.get(globals.api_base_href+this.apiUrl+ (++this.pagenum));

  }


}
```

Comment: Please post the services code: `NowRunningServiceService` and `YoutubeService`

Comment: fixed it. see the answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the service that caused  CORS issue was missing "access-control-allow-origin" header in the original response. So Intercepted and added this header.

```
router.get('/*', function (req,res, next) {
  res.header('access-control-allow-origin','*')
  next();
});
```